# output using Apache POI from an executable results in question marks (wrong encoding?)

Tags: java, apache-poi, launch4j

I/O using Apache POI from an IDE works fine, but when exporting it in a runnable JAR and then have it wrapped in an exe, the output turns out to be question marks only. And since XWPFDocument only writes to an OutputStream, explicitly specifying the encoding is not possible. So, what would be a solution to this?
Here's the relevant code:

```
try (var WordOutput = new FileOutputStream(whichFile, true);
                var MSDoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(whichFile));)
        {   //inside try block now
            List<XWPFTable> tables = MSDoc.getTables();
            tables.toArray();
    var ArabicRow = ArabicTable.getRow(0);
                ArabicRow.getCell(1).removeParagraph(0);
                //adding a paragraph with a right alignment:
                XWPFParagraph arabicParagraph = ArabicRow.getCell(1).addParagraph();
                arabicParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
                
                 CTP ctp = arabicParagraph.getCTP();
                  CTPPr ctppr;
                  if ((ctppr = ctp.getPPr()) == null) ctppr = ctp.addNewPPr();
                  ctppr.addNewBidi().setVal(true);
                
                //a Run is the content of the paragraph, plus other properties.
                XWPFRun arabicSentence = arabicParagraph.createRun();
                
                String theString = "\u202E" + (Arabic text here) + "\u202C";
                 MSDoc.write(WordOutput);
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            //my exception handler
        }
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: Where did the arabic text come from? How did you get it into your program? Could you have got the encoding wrong on the text on the way in?

Comment: maybe edit (in Excel)/save/unzip the generated file and compare it's sheet*.xml and opt. sharedStrings.xml with the generated one.

Comment: @Gagravarr, from a TextArea (using JavaFx). Then I store it in a variable:
```
String s = myTextArea.getText();
```
then I use the encoding to fix a directionality issue (when there are parenthesis and other characters, the output would get messy until I did so).
Also, that's a good point, doesn't the output control the final encoding?

Comment: @kiwiwings, it's MS Word, but where do I find its xml metadata? I looked into that too, found nothing.

Comment: @Mobbs8 sorry, I have mixed it up before. a *.docx (or *.xlsx/*.pptx) file is a *.zip file - so you can unzip it. You can then compare the "word\document.xml" file before/after your modifications. I would copy/edit the file generated by POI - otherwise you will have more structural differences

Comment: @kiwiwings, aha. How come? winrar shows "compress"...how could they be .zip files? this is interesting!
but anywhere where I could explicitly change the encoding (now checking editing the registry) should probably work. Except I couldn't tell where the actual XML Apache POI writes to is.

Comment: @kiwiwings, I just got what you meant. Very interesting! I just copied the file manipulated by POI (it's not created by it though), and renaming it to a zip file then viewing the XML files, DID show that the encoding is UTF-8. Ouch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved it!
the problem was me encoding a string from UTF-8 to UTF-8 again, which apparently made no sense. I'm leaving this answer since what made troubleshooting this problem kinda tough was the fact that there are 3 components to my program.

1. Apache POI (which has been my suspect all the time).
2. JavaFX
3. Java (the JVM, to be exact).
   I got the string written to the word file from a TextArea, which, during another bug-hunt I would encode into UTF-8:

```
String theString = new String(theTextArea.getText().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

I had solved that bug but this constructor looked too beautiful for me to change it back to just:

```
String theString = theTextArea.getText();
```

Voila, I ran the program to have it compiled, exported it, did everything normally and the problem is gone. I hope those who have such problem find this answer. And I apologize for my stupidity, XD.